# Rsync a certain number of sub-directories

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, symbolic-link, jenkins

I'm currently working on migrating almost 80 jenkins servers for our company into a single jenkins server. I've already worked out how this will appear once we get the jobs migrated, however getting the jobs over is proving to be somewhat difficult.

What I currently have is an rsync command that pulls over all jobs and builds and is working fine, but this is no longer viable on bloated servers:

```
sshpass -p '*****' \
rsync -rmvptgolD \
--exclude='*/archive/*' \
--include='legacyIds' \
--include='nextBuildNumber' \
--include='last*Build' \
--include='log' \
--include='*.txt' \
--include='*.html' \
--include='build.xml' \
--include='changelog.xml' \
--include='config.xml' \
--include='*/' \
--exclude='*' \
-e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l user' \
user@server:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ \
/<destination>/jobs
```

yes I know `sshpass` is insecure, these servers were created far before my time and we cannot add keys to them to make this a secure connection, for now I'm stuck with the `sshpass` part.

This rsync command works perfectly fine on jenkins servers that don't have many jobs/builds, but the one I ran into is forcing me to cut back on information that we're pretty sure no one even needs anymore.

I've come across one server now that has over 5,000 jobs and each one has around 50,000 builds which is overkill, thus instating the goals below

The end goal is to copy:

> All jobs and the last 10 builds for each job

OR

> All jobs and the last failed build and last successful build for each job

My main question, is how can I add in an rsync filter of some sort to only include the last 10 subdirectories? or something like that. OR keep symlinks AND copy it's link as a separate entity?

this is an example of a Jenkins server's folder structure:

```
jenkins/
  config.xml
  jobs/
    Job1/
      config.xml
      builds/
        1/
          build.xml
          archive/
          log
        2/
          build.xml
          archive/
          log
        3/
          build.xml
          archive/
          log
        4/
          build.xml
          archive/
          log
        n/
          build.xml
          archive/
          log
        lastFailedBuild/ -> 3/
        lastSuccessfulBuild/ -> 4/
    Job2/
      ...
```

Where the build/[0-9]*/ directories are the build ID in jenkins.

Any help at all would be much appreciated, I quickly looked into the -L option but that looks like it removes the symlink, same with -K and -k

Thank you!

Comment: Use other means (find, awk, sed,...) to get the exact list of files to transfer and present them to rsync with `--files-from=filelist`

Comment: that's a good idea, I'll give it a shot